# Dropdown menu is cutting off in jquery ui modal dialog

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-select2, jquery-ui-dialog

Using `select2` in `jquery.ui.dialog`.
The problem is when the dropdown menu is open it won't overflow outside the dialog as the native `<select>` does but just pushes the dialog height bigger.

How to detach `select2` dropdown menu from the document flow so that the menu doesn't cut off?

I have already tried to increase dropdownmenu's `z-index` and change `jquery.ui.dialog` overflow rules. But none of these seem to have any effect.

```
<div id="myDialog">   
    <select id="myselect">
      <option>Select2Foo</option>
      <option>Select2Bar1</option>
      <option>Select2Bar2</option>
      <option>Select2Bar3</option>
      <option>Select2Bar4</option>
      <option>Select2Bar5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen  : true,
    modal     : true,
    title     : "A Dialog Box",   
    width: "90%",
});


$('#myselect').select2({
  dropdownParent: $('#myDialog')
})
```

It "cuts off" / is in the document flow pushing the modal bigger.
[image]

I'd rather want it to behave as native select
[image]

The fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/anmatika/dy3am21n/1/

Comment: Please add more details like HTML and CSS in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does select2 have a different stylesheet to use with jquery UI? I know they have separate CSS to use with bootsrap.

Comment: I removed the `dropdownParent: $('#myDialog')` option from the `select2` init, and it worked as intended.

Comment: `select2` has its own stylesheet, yes. And I am not aware it having any different CSS which would be meant to be used with `jquery.ui`

Comment: As per my experience If I remove `dropdownParent` it will attach to `body` element and render itself outside of the dialog.
Not in the fiddle though but in real world solution it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question since got it working and this could be helpful to others in the future.

`jquery.ui.dialog` creates a wrapper `.ui-dialog` around the element you want to make as a dialog.

You'd need *the both*, your dialog element and the jquery.ui dialog wrapper, to have `overflow: visible` set.

```
.ui-dialog,
#myDialog {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anmatika/dy3am21n/22/